# Sublime Text Ctrl R move selection to top of page

Tags: sublimetext3

I use `Ctrl+R` to find functions in Sublime Text 3. This is very handy except it only requires that the selected text come into view, usually somewhere at the bottom of the screen.

I would like the selection to be pushed to the top of the page, or even better, to a set line in the middle of the page. Can this be accomplished with sublime user settings?

Comment: That's not the behavior I get using Build 3095 on Linux - it appears in the middle of the screen. What build/OS are you using?

Comment: If you know the function name, why not just `Ctrl+F`?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04. This is still a handy macro for looking for functions specifically